# question on Riemann $\zeta(s)$

Tags: complex-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

I have a question that is troubling me.

From the functional equation of $\zeta(s)$, can we not conclude that both $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(1-s)$ have the same non-trivial zeros (differing at most in the sense that roots of one is the complex conjugate of the other and vice versa) and if this were true doesn't this imply RH?

Thanks

Comment: No. It just shows that the non-trivial zeros are symmetric about the point $s=1/2$.

Comment: What if $\xi(s) = (s-1/4)(s-3/4)$ ? (where $\xi(s)$ satisfy $\xi(s) = \xi(1-s)$, which is the case with $\xi(s) =\Gamma(s/2)\pi^{-s/2} \zeta(s)$)

Comment: @reuns, Do you have an example for when the equation has no real zeros? Thanks

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: To be clear the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$ means $\xi(s) =\Gamma(s/2)\pi^{-s/2} \zeta(s)$ satisfies $\xi(s)  =\xi(1-s)$ which means $\Xi(s) = \xi(1/2+s) = \Xi(-s)$ is even, that's all. Now there are many even functions, but the even functions coming from a Dirichlet series  are much more rare and they satisfy a lot of nice properties.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$f(z) = z(1-z) - i$$

This satisfies $$f(z) = f(1-z)$$

but none of the zeroes have $\mathrm{Re}(z) = \dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks. Here $f(z) = f(1-z)$. In other words they are identical. Is it fair to say that $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(1-s)$ are not identical but they have the same non-trivial zeros? I don't know if I am making sense... Thanks again.

Comment: @sku: So you want a function $f$ such that for some $h$, $h(f(z)) = h(f(1-z))$, but $f(z) \ne f(1-z)$ and $f$ has zeroes not on $Re(z) = 1/2$?

Comment: @sku Of course $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(1-s)$ have the same non-trivial zeros... The functional equation say $\zeta(s) = \chi(s) \zeta(1-s)$ for some function $\chi(s)$ analytic and non-zero for $\Im(s) \ne 0$.

Comment: If you look at the expression $f(s) = \sum\frac{ (-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$ and if $f(s)$ has a root at $1/2 + bi$, then we can show that $f(1-s)$ has a root at $1/2 - bi$. So I was thinking that if we can prove that roots of $f(s)$ and $f(1-s)$ must be complex conjugates, then this would imply real part of root = $1/2$.

Comment: My last thought on this is: if $a + bi$ is a root of $\zeta(s)$ then $1-a-bi$ should also be a root because of the relationship between $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(1-s)$. And these two roots are identical. Hence we should be able to conclude $a = 1-a$ or $a = 1/2$. This is all probably very wrong. I will leave it at this.. Thanks to all who responded. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Aryabhata, to answer your question consider f(z) with real coefficients but complex roots.

Comment: @Sku: $f(z) = (\sin 2\pi z)^2$

Comment: @Aryabhata, what are the non-trivial zeros of $f(z) = (\sin 2\pi z)^2$?

Comment: @sku: What is your definition of non-trivial?